# Password authentication error in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I just installed postgresql in Ubuntu and I'm trying to run a server that initiates a database connection:

```
var db = new Sequelize('db', '', null, {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  port: 5432
);}
```

I'm getting this error when I initialize the server:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: password authentication failed for user "myUser"
```

I think it's trying to run postgresql with my Ubuntu user. How can I set up another user to be the default postgresql user? I already tried `createuser --interactive` but it did not solve the authentication error.

Comment: From the doc: `var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  dialect: "postgres",
  port: 12345
})`. You should first create a user on postgres and provide the credentials here. Create a database if you haven't already and put the database name there.

Comment: @RahulSharma Thanks for the suggestion! I'm now able to initialize the server when providing the user credentials to sequelize. I was wondering if there is a way to bypass the postgres authentication, so that I can still have user = '' and password = null